# Remote Installation of "Remotely" app via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-access

My organization uses a software called *Remotely* for remote access to some of our users devices. I'm trying to find a way to install the software remotely via PowerShell. I have the installer file copied locally on the root of the C drive on each machine. Here is what I've tried.

```
enterPS C:\Users\USER> Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTEPC -ScriptBlock {
Start-Process C:\Remotely_Installer.exe -install -quiet -organizationid "IDSTRING" -serverurl "https://remotely.CORP.com"
}
```

Running this command returns a "Paramater cannot be found that matches the names "install." This is what is on *Remotely's* website but it doesn't specify anything for remote installation via PowerShell.

```
Remotely_Installer.exe -install -quiet -organizationid "0b3d706b-9c5d-41e6-8ae9-5720d16324e6" -serverurl "https://remotely.mytechshop.com"
```

Ideally I'd be able to have a simple script where I can have the user copy the file to their C drive and then I can run the script, target their device, and have it show up in the remote management portal.

Comment: `-install` is an argument for the installer, not `Start-Process`. Change it to `Start-Process C:\Remotely_Installer.exe -ArgumentList '-install','-quiet','-organizationid','"IDSTRING"','-serverurl','"https://remotely.CORP.com"'`

Comment: That seems to be an improvement but did not work. I ran the following.

`
PS C:\Users\USER> Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTEPC -ScriptBlock {
>> Start-Process C:\Remotely_Install-[09ce].exe -ArgumentList '-install','-quiet','-organizationid','"IDSTRING"','-serverurl','"https://remotely.CORP.com"'
>> }
`

After running this PowerShell hung for three or four seconds and then returns me to a new line waiting for a new command. This is what it does when I install the software locally. However, the program does not show up in my installed programs list nor does it appear online.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  Start-process isn't needed that often, except to wait for something started in the background.  This assumes the installer is already on the remote computer.

```
# $s = new-pssession remotepc
# copy-item C:\Remotely_Installer.exe c:\ -tosession $s  # slow
Invoke-Command REMOTEPC {
  C:\Remotely_Installer.exe -install -quiet -organizationid IDSTRING -serverurl https://remotely.CORP.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it installed with the following command inside a .bat file

```
start "" "path\Remotely_Install.exe" -install -quiet -supportshortcut -organizationid "yourOrganizationId" -serverurl "yourServerUrl"
```